# How do I roll-back a message to Amazon MQ (AMQ) from Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, activemq-classic, stomp

So, I assume this relates to any Node.js and Active MQ installation but I am using Amazon MQ with Node.js Lambda...

Kind of a noob on ActiveMQ so please correct me where I am wrong!

After reading a message from a queue using `stompit` I continue processing the message and it shall then be sent over HTTPS to another server.
There is some message validation and enrichment happening on the way to the HTTPS POST, and of course the POST itself can result in an error.

How would I (best) handle a roll-back of the message in case of an error:

1) Keep the connection open and not send `client.ack()` until I finally got a HTTP 200 back from remote server?

2) Keep the message in a variable and put it back in case of error (sequence doesn't matter?

3) Use something other than stomp?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `message.nack()`?  Or if not that, `client.destroy()` (because the server should redeliver any messages you didn't ack before dropping the connection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is apparently not possible using STOMP so I've changed the code to use the library ampq10 instead.

```
import amqp10 from 'amqp10';

const AMQPClient = amqp10.Client;

const amqpClient = new AMQPClient({
  receiverLink: {
    attach: {
      rcvSettleMode: amqp10.Constants.receiverSettleMode.settleOnDisposition
    },
    creditQuantum: 1
  }
});
```

This will allow you to do a `receiver.accept(message);` if successfully handling the message. If you just `.disconnect()` whitout an `.accept()` the message will not be removed from the queue.